# Не работают printf в одном потоке

Tags: c++, многопоточность, printf

У меня есть проект, в котором нужно, что бы печатало несколько `printf` в одном потоке. Я столкнулся с проблемой, что захватывается только самый последний `printf`. Перепробовал несколько вариантов `fflush`, но безуспешно.

Код для теста:

```
#include <thread>

int main(){

for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
//...
for(int x = 1; x<10; x++){
    printf("\rValue of I is: %d", i);

    //fflush(stdout);
    printf("\rValue of X is: %d", x);
    
//...
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}
}
system ("pause");
return 0;
```

}

[image: Печатается только второй printf]

Что я делаю не так? И как правильно нужно делать? Я хочу, что бы оба вывода изменялись в этой же строке. За ранее спасибо за подсказку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробую угадать - вы пишете `"\r blablabla"`

Но `\r` - это команда *возврат каретки*, она перегоняет курсор в начало строки. Две выведенные вами строки сливаются в одну.

Нужно это поправить, например, убрав `\r` во втором `printf`

После этого, можно исправить вторую проблему - поставить `fflush(stdout);` непосредственно перед `sleep()`

Comment: может не убирать `"\r"`, а добавить перевод строки `"\r\n"` ?

Comment: Моя догадка состоит в том, что автор вопроса хочет видеть на экране одну строку, в которой бегает число.

Comment: тогда верно, останется красоту навести : `"%6d\t"`

Comment: Здравствуйте! Спасибо за решение, это что было нужно. Если вас не затруднит, можете подсказать, как перенести 2-й `printf` на следующую строку, что бы `printf("\rValue of I is: %d\t", i);` был на одной строке, а `printf("Value of X is: %d", x);` был на следующей. Из-за цикла `\n` печатает заново, что затруднительно для меня.